# XDegug session termination (PDT)

Tags: php, debugging, xdebug, eclipse-pdt

When I terminate XDebug session in PDT, cookies are not removed and session is still active. Thus, each debugging session I need to terminate manually with XDEBUG_SESSION_STOP in browser, otherwise, Xdebug keep trying to connect even when I run scripts without debugging. Is it an PDT issue, or maybe I'm doing something wrong? My configuration: Eclipse 4.4.2, Xdebug 2.3.1, Windows 7 x64.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bug, you have to disable "jit" in debug configuration to ignore debug session restoration, or remove cookie manually (for example by firefox/chrome plugin).

Bug report: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=460836